# looping not exiting and not printing the results at the end

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was hoping to create a code to output if a next number entered is Up, Down or Same as the first one. I wanted it to exit when '0' is entered. I also wanted it to print the 'Up', 'Down', or 'Same' result at the end when exited with '0' instead of each time a number is entered.(if user enters: 4, 6, 1, 1, then 0 to exit, the final output will be Up, Down, Same printed.) Please tell me what I am missing, here is what i have so far:

```
firstNumber = input('Please enter your first number:')

nextNumber=input('Enter the next number(0 to finish)')

while nextNumber !=0:

    if firstNumber<nextNumber:
        print ('Up')

    elif firstNumber>nextNumber:
        print ('Down')

    elif firstNumber==nextNumber:
        print ('Same')

    firstNumber = nextNumber

    nextNumber=input('Enter the next number(0 to finish)')
```

Comment: `input()` `return`s a string in Python 3, `'0'` not `0`, you need `int(input())`

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing string, not numbers.

You should cast your input to integers with `int()`.

here:

```
try:
    firstNumber = int(input('Please enter your first number:'))
    nextNumber = int(input('Enter the next number(0 to finish)'))
except ValueError:
    # Handle cast error here
    pass
while nextNumber !=0:
    ...
```

**Note**

As blubberdiblub explained:

- `<` `>` compare pointer code of strings, that means `"8" < "10"` returns `False` while `8 < 10` returns `True`

Comment: Actually, `<` and `>` will compare strings in code point order (i.e. `'a' < 'b'` -> `True`). But otherwise a nice answer.

Comment: You are right, just tested it. I always thought otherwise.

Comment: You can still point out that for numbers in strings `"8" < "10"` would result in `False` while `8 < 10` (i. e. numbers) will result in `True`. So in essence it was a fair point to make.

Answer (score 0):

**input**

> The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.

So use

```
int(input(...))
```

Comment: thank you, how about collectively printing the outputs when exited.

Comment: Hint: start a new list on top of `while loop` .Append your outputs to that list. Print output list after `while` code block.